# Image file size estimation

Tags: image, pixel, aspect-ratio

How to calculate the image file size given:

> Image width (in pixel): 70/ 300/ 640 &
>
> Width to height aspect ratio. Ex: 1.5

Comment: I answered but please give a litlle more details.  And also show w some effort

Answer (score 2):

In order to calculate image size you need to say which format.  Some formats have headers which are a few bytes and some are a few kb.  there are also headerless images some of the (*.Raw). Next you need to know how many bits or bytes per pixel. Each color can be represented in different bits accurate. 
Then you do header + (width *height *bytes per pixel) .  This is what you basically want to do.

Comment: Image is in Jpg format.

Comment: @Ram, it is absolutely impossible to calculate this for a JPG, since JPEG is a lossy compression format.  The file size will depend on the image composition and the amount of compression (JPEG quality).